# Optimization Problem (Paul Krugman's book)

Tags: optimization, economics

I have an optimization problem. I understand the result of the first-order condition. What I don't understand is how the author arrives at equation 4.6. This is from Paul Krugman's book ("The Spatial Economy").

The problem:
\begin{equation}
min \int_{0}^{n} p(i)m(i) \,di \, \,\,\, s.t \,\,\,\,\left[    \int_{0}^{n} m(i)^{\rho} \,di   \right]^{\frac{1}{\rho}} = M  \tag{4.3}
\end{equation}

Fist-order condition:

\begin{equation}
\frac{m(i)^{\rho-1}}{m(j)^{\rho-1}}=\frac{p(i)}{p(j)} \,\,|\,\,i \neq j \tag{4.4}     
\end{equation}

solving equation 4.4 for m(i):

\begin{equation}
m(i) = m(j)  \left( \frac{p(i)}{p(j)} \right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} \notag{}
\end{equation}

replacing $m(i)$ in the constraint and solving for m(j):

\begin{equation}
\left[    \int_{0}^{n} \left( \left( \frac{p(i)}{p(j)} \right)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}} \right)^{\rho} \,di   \right]^{\frac{1}{\rho}} = M
\notag{}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
m(j) = \frac{p(j)^{\frac{1}{\rho-1}}}{\left[    \int_{0}^{n} p(i)^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}} \,di   \right]^{\frac{1}{\rho}}}M
\tag{4.5}
\end{equation}

the problem is in the following equation. I don't know how the author arrived at this equation. He just says:  "using (4.5) and integrating over all j gives"

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{n} p(j)m(j)\,dj = \left[    \int_{0}^{n} p(i)^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}} \,di   \right]^{\frac{\rho-1}{\rho}}
\tag{4.6}
\end{equation}

I would be grateful if someone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides of (4.5) by $p(j)$:
$$p(j)m(j) = \frac{ p(j)p(j)^{\frac1{p-1}}}{C^{\frac{1}p}} M=\frac{p(j)^{\frac p{p-1}}}{C^{\frac{1}p}} M\tag1$$
where for brevity we write $$C:=\int_0^np(i)^{\frac p {p-1}}di.$$ Now integrate over $j$. Then (1) becomes
$$\int_0^np(j)m(j)\,dj=\frac{\int_0^np(j)^{\frac p{p-1}}\,dj}{C^{\frac{1}p}} M=
\frac{C}{C^{\frac{1}p}}M =C^{\frac{p-1}p}M=\left[\int_0^np(i)^{\frac p {p-1}}di\right]^{\frac{p-1}p}M.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your simplification. But I don't understand why you considered the following equality as well: $C =  \int_{0}^{n} p(j)^{\frac{\rho}{\rho-1}} \,dj $. Is 'j' not different from 'i' in this case?

Comment: In $C$ the $i$ is a 'dummy' variable of integration. $C$ has the same value if we replace all occurrences of $i$ with $j$. In other words, $\int _a^b f(x)\,dx=\int_a^b f(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much.